# Reading an HTTP stream into an array

Tags: php

I need to read an http stream into an array but can't seem to get this quite right. Ultimately, what I need is an array of the html to use in an implode function. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What code are you using that isn't quite right?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the HTML, then the easiest way is:

```
$content=file_get_contents('http://url.of.the.site');
```